# Quotes, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, string

I feel daft asking this, but it's driving me potty. How can I make this string:

```
Children\''s Toy
```

Suitable for insert to a MySQL database and escape the characters properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) should do it.
If you are using the `mysqli` extension, you can do it the same way. ( `mysqli_real_escape_string` )

Comment: This led me to the solution. I was using the following:

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$value = stripslashes($value);
}$return_value = "'" . str_replace("'", "''", $value) . "'";

but i had to call stripslashes() before i even used this bit of code and that solved my problem... the Notes on the link you supplied helped. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why, by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), of course.

Comment: Yes, PDO and prepared statements are the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I'll give it a try in my next project

Comment: Sure, enjoy the SQL injections in the meantime :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Children\\\'\'s Toy
```

But you really should be relying on something built into PHP like [`mysql_reql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or better yet, parameterize queries using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Here's my test of the above:

```
mysql> select 'Children\\\'\'s Toy' as escapedString;
+------------------+
| escapedString    |
+------------------+
| Children\''s Toy |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.49 sec)
```